# How to write(send) command to USB Port?(UVC, Webcam)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webcam, uvc

I am new in c#

I am trying to send command to USB port(usbport=========fx3(Cypress chip), to light on LED than with in the custom board))

I tried to scanport but it was failed because my computer(win10) recognized the usb as camera(fx3 is chip that image processing)

so i found this code in sysnet.pe.kr

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ListDevices().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task ListDevices()
        {
        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);

            foreach (var item in devices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id}: {item.Name}");
                devices.            
            }
         }

    }
}
```

it works!!! so I found port

but i don't have idea how to send command to the port!!!

please help me ㅠㅠ

Comment: Can you post here some link to the manufacturer / custom board model? Maybe we can give a look and try to find some documentation or sample code.

Comment: thanks a lot
http://www.cypress.com/products/ez-usb-fx3-superspeed-usb-30-peripheral-controller

here is url

the chip is fx3 CYUSB3014-BZXC

Answer (score 0):

First you must read your camera documentation (from producer website or .. , it may have programing sdk)

Otherwise you can use [LibUsbDotNet](https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet)

Comment: thanks your reply
http://www.cypress.com/products/ez-usb-fx3-superspeed-usb-30-peripheral-controller

here is url

the chip is fx3 CYUSB3014-BZXC

Comment: Download SDK from this link http://www.cypress.com/documentation/software-and-drivers/ez-usb-fx3-software-development-kit